# Route testing with Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, pytest

I'm new to Tornado, and working on a project that involves some rather complex routing. In most of the other frameworks I've used I've been able to isolate routing for testing, without spinning up a server or doing anything terribly complex. I'd prefer to use pytest as my testing framework, but I'm not sure it matters.

Is there a way to, say, create my project's instance of `tornado.web.Application`, and pass it arbitrary paths and assert which `RequestHandler` will be invoked based on that path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to test this in Tornado via any public interface (as of Tornado version 4.3).

It's straightforward to avoid spinning up a server, although it requires a nontrivial amount of code: the interface between HTTPServer and Application is well-defined and documented. The trickier part is the other side: there is no supported way to determine which handler will be invoked before that handler *is* invoked.

I generally recommend testing routing via end-to-end tests for this reason. You could also store your URL route list before passing it into Tornado, and do your tests against that - the internal logic of "take the first regex match" is pretty easy to replicate.